# How to allow tap-to-focus on the camera using an overlay

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

The standard 3GS iPhone camera includes tap-to-focus (I can tap to the region I want to focus on). However when I use a custom overlay using the UIImagePickerController class, the tap to focus does not seem to work. Everything else in terms of capturing images programmatically etc is working btw.

Note that my overlay view is only a small rectangle (UIView) at the bottom of the screen. It does not cover the other areas of the camera. So I believe the taps should go through (unless I am missing something). I have seen other apps use an overlay and still provide a tap-to-focus functionality, so there must be a way to do this.

I use all the default controls set to be hidden as:

```
imagePicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
imagePicker.toolbarHidden = YES;
imagePicker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

Of course changing the above does not let me tap-to-focus (it just enables the toolbars, etc).

I could not find any answers on the UIImagePickerController class reference. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I just found out the answer is pretty simple. Whether you see a square or not, when you touch the screen, it does work. Try it. You just need to draw your own square with animation.